# Finding the selected TinyMCE editor via jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Is there a way to find the currently active (selected) TinyMCE editor among multiple instances?

```
$(document).tinymce();
```

This code finds an array of all instances, but how do we know which one is currently active/selected/focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
tinymce.activeEditor
```

This will deliver `null` if no editor is active (for example if the user has not clicked into an editor at all) or the last editor object/instance that has been active.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like this (untested):

```
$(document).tinymce().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(':focus').length > 0;
});
```

Comment: No this doesn't return anything, because TinyMCE is a rather complex component that cannot simply be detected with ':focus'

Comment: Well, what do you define as active? I define it as, my cursor is in the editor so it has focus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tinyMCE but if it uses standard textareas, you could do something like this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currTinyMCEID = '';
</script>

<textarea id="tinymce_1" onchange='setActive(this)'></textarea>
<textarea id="tinymce_2" onchange='sectActive(this)'></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setActive(elem)
{
    currTinyMCEID = elem.id;
}
</script>
```

By binding to onchange, the "active" Tiny MCE would be the one most recently edited.